# How is memory compression achieved.?

Tags: linux, memory, compression

How is memory compression achieved.? What is compcache..? How do I choose an appropriate technique for my system (its a telecom sw - running on SMP LINUX (from Windriver system)+Cavium Octeon processor)). There is just a physical memory of 2 GB with no swap.

Answer (score 0):

Memory compression is achieved through application of information theory. Check out a few articles on [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) and [data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression).